# How to pass an activity context in an application to a service in an other application

Tags: android, service, android-context

So I have an activity in an application that starts a service:

```
private void startService() {
    if (started) {
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Service already started",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.enorbitas.daemon.service",
                "com.enorbitas.daemon.service.DaemonService");
        startService(i);
        started = true;
        updateServiceStatus();
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "startService()");
    }

}
```

The activity is launched by the following intent:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The service then does the logging and connects with this custom usb device. In order to do that, it needs the activity context:

```
        mUsbManager = (UsbManager) parent.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
        while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
            UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
        }

        Intent intent = parent.getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent
                .getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
            setDevice(device);
            Log.i(TAG, "usb conectado");
        } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
            if (mDevice != null && mDevice.equals(device)) {
                setDevice(null);
                Log.i(TAG, "usb NO conectado");
            }
        }
```

parent would be the activity that starts the service. This approach used to work because that code used to be in the same application, but now I want it to be a service so that others applications can connect to it.

Is there a way to pass the context of the activity to the service? I read a lot about intents and bundles, parcelable and serialization, but none of it works for me. I need to pass the context.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) has its own Context, just use that. You don't need to pass a Service an Activity's Context.

I don't see why you need a specific Activity's Context to call `getSystemService()` and a Service will receive Intents from a BroadcastReceiver as readily as any Activity.

Also, if the originating Activity is destroyed while this Service is running, the Context will be invalid or the Activity will be leaked.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But the problem is that when I get the intent from the parent in order to get the .getParcelableExtra and ask for the device it returns null. For me that happens because the intent that catches the usb attachment is the one from the activity, not the service. I think that's what's going on. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: But your BroadcastReceiver can pass this information to the Service directly, it doesn't need to be stored in an Activity.

Comment: Because I tried with the context of the service and I always get null pointer when retrieving the usb device object. How would you do it? If a set the service to catch the intent of the usb attachement it just never gets called. I don't know why Android has an issue with that specific intent filter.

Comment: But the BroadcastReceiver would never receive the intent from the usb attach. Android has a bug or something like that. It only works for an intent filter in an activity.

Comment: "I tried with the context of the service and I always get null pointer when retrieving the usb device object." Interesting (I'll give it a try myself.) However you can always pass the extra's Parcelable data in a new Intent or you can use [UsbManager#getDeviceList()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html#getDeviceList%28%29).

Comment: When I use getDeviceList() I can retrieve them. It's when I call the .getParcelableExtra that I get null. Actually that's really odd or I am doing something wrong. But you can't pass a context as an extra, right? I also tried that. The parcelable data it's always a String or something like that.

Comment: "But you can't pass a context as an extra, right?" Not that I'm aware of, you can only pass primitive or parcelable data types. I have never used `EXTRA_DEVICE` so I don't know it's peculiarities. But as long as you can receive the `ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` (and detached) Intents, you can use `getDeviceList()` to retreive the device's name.

Comment: can we check location permission in services?

Answer (score 0):

> How to pass an activity context in an application to a service in an other application

This is not possible. These applications are running in separate virtual machines in separate applications -- you cannot pass an object across these boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Interprocess communication might help you there.

[Some randomly googled Android IPC slides here](http://kobablog.wordpress.com/2011/06/04/inter-process-communication-of-android/)